# Fiddler 401 error /_api/web

Tags: rest

I am requesting this url with fiddler: `http://sitecollectionUrl/_api/web`

With the header of:

```
Accept:   application/json;odata=verbose
```

But I am getting 401 error code when doing so. I am on SharePoint Server 2013.

Comment: Have you checked Automatically Authenticate option or you have key in the Authorization in header?

Comment: How do I check the authentication automatically? No I don't have a header for authentication.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I found the automate authentication, and it worked. Please add it as answer so I can mark it :) thank you a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable the Automatically Authenticate option in Fiddler. It will use your current Windows logon account to send the request.

The option can be found under **Composer** tab > **Options** tab